# twitter bootstrap popover title

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

When building a twitter bootstrap pop over, you often have the title placed in using the `data-original-title` how ever, I am curious as to what that titles css class is, if it has one.

The reason is, I need to change the position of the title inside the header of the popover. I have tried `.popover-title` but it moved the title and the grey header backdrop down, I just want to move the title

Comment: Is your selector specific enough?

Comment: Not clear what the problem is, this is 100% `.popover-title`.

Comment: What do you mean by **Change position** ? like : position:absolute; top:0 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change position in what way ?

Just over-write this declaration

```
.popover-title {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the title of a popover has the class `popover-title`. So any changes you want to make will have to be there.

However, the grey backdrop is all part of the popover-title class too, so any changes will have to take that into account. e.g. adding `text-align:right` to the class works fine.

How are you trying to change the position? What are you trying to achieve? If you really wanted to go crazy you could alter the template for the popover in bootstrap-popover.js to add another class or something, but it depends on what you are trying to do.